# Handing when ngRepeat has no items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm rendering table rows using ngRepeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="User in ReportModel.report" on-finish-render>
    <td><span>{{User.name}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

I have this `on-finish-render` directive to emit an event if listen for to let me know when the table is ready:

```
app.directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is what's happening when the ngRepeatFinished event is emitted in the controller:

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
    //set a variable to true which datatables directive is watching
    //when that variable is true, initiate datatables
    $rootScope.ReportReady = true;
});
```

Then I have DataTables directive looking for when the report is ready:

```
  scope.$watch(
    function() {
      return $rootScope.ReportReady
    },
    function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue) {
        var dTable = element.dataTable(scope.options);
        $rootScope.ReportVisible = true;
      }
    });
```

Problem is sometimes there isn't any items in the Report so the event isn't emitted and the dataTable doesn't display.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What event creates `ReportModel.report`?

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-show or ng-hide to show or hide the table based on if there is data in ReportModel.report.  So just check if the data is null to show or hide.

Comment: I updated the OP. `ng-show/ng-hide` won't work. Right now I'm initiating `dataTables()` when the event is triggered. I still want to initiate DataTables even if the list is empty.

Comment: Then why set an event to trigger when the data comes back?  There is 2 way data binding so just render the table right away...and when the data actually returns...the data will be filled in and Angular will populate the table and no on-render event is needed.

Comment: You're right, I need to redo my dataTables implementation. It's kind of a mess. Anyways, for now I was able to solve this by doing a check when the dataloads to see if there's anything and set the table as ready right away:  `if ($scope.ReportModel.report.length === 0){$rootScope.ReportReady = true;}`